# How to use CELL function within LINEST?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am calculating quadratic regression and using the LINEST function. Each item has 4 or 5 x and y values. there are 100's of items.

Example data set would look like this in table form,

ID      year    Safety factor

408381  2005    4.06

408381  2009    4.06

408381  2012    3.27

408383  2005    3.28

408383  2009    3.28

408383  2012    3.27

408385  2005    3.17

408385  2009    3.16

408385  2012    3.15

364881  2005    4.49

364881  2009    4.49

364881  2012    4.47

I'm trying to use CELL("address") to get cell range to use in known_y's and known_x's for LINEST.
This is what I am using,

```
=LINEST(CELL("address",INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A12,A:A,0))):CELL("address",INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A12,A:A))),
CELL("address",INDEX(C:C, MATCH(A12,A:A,0))):(CELL("address",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A12,A:A))))^{1,2})
```

the individual functions all work separately, but when combined into LINEST there is a problem. can anyone help solve this? 
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Would you post some example data, and explain the purpose of using `CELL("address")` with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CELL function returns a string.  Try the following instead...

```
=LINEST(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A12,A:A,0)):INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A12,A:A)),
INDEX(C:C, MATCH(A12,A:A,0)):INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A12,A:A))^{1,2})
```

Comment: Thank you @Domenic. That did the trick, good to know LINEST can work this way.